# Migrate a MongoDB collection from default file system to GridFS

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection with several thousand documents. Since I've to support storing some huge documents (that are over 16MB in size), I'm planning to switch the use GridFS.

I couldn't find any documentation on migrating the data from the default file system to GridFS. Is there any command or utility available to achieve this or should I write my own script?

Thanks

Comment: There are no such documentation. You confuse purpose of [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/). It is a solution to store **files** within mongodb. Files are not documents. Converting documents to files you wont be able to execute any collection commands on them.

Comment: Oh! I misunderstood it totally then. Thanks for the clarification.